# What would have happened if Thor reached ground before breaking the glass?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, the-avengers-2012

In *The Avengers*, Loki says to Thor, “The humans think us immortal; let’s put that to the test”, and drops the glass chamber.

Loki clearly knows that Thor is an immortal and he is doing this to scatter the Avengers, so what would have happened if the glass chamber reached the ground before Thor could break it??

Would Thor have been killed or injured?

Comment: `Loki clearly knows that Thor is an immortal` ~> Seriously, what makes you think so...

Comment: This is unknown - they were testing it.  However, Thor is killable and so it Loki otherwise there would be little point in them fighting and Thor would not have been bothered when Loki stabbed him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Asgardians are *not* immortals. They are simply long-lived and powerful, but can be killed.

Odin states this explicitly in *Thor: The Dark World*. And it's confirmed later in that film, with

> the death of Frigga, Thor's mother, by stabbing.

So to answer your question, there's no reason to suppose Thor would not be killed.